# Show Product custom option in reorder using observer in Magento

Tags: magento

I have added custom product option in product using observer it works fine. But how to show at reorder time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello chhitij use following event-

```
   <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>module_name/observer</class>
                    <method>checkout_cart_product_add_after</method>
                </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

and use same thing as show custom options at order time..